# Specific Website content removal via Greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, html, tampermonkey, greasemonkey-4

I know similar questions have been asked countless times, I've been reading through them for a while now, but I can't seem to get it to work for my case, I've read through the following and tried to apply those solutions to my case, all from Stack Overflow, but I have not had success, so I'd appreciate the help.

[Article 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9169032/how-to-use-greasemonkey-to-selectively-remove-content-from-a-website) [Article 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48462714/how-to-use-greasemonkey-to-selectively-remove-content-from-a-website) [Article 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23413400/greasemonkey-script-to-remove-html-between-specific-comments) [Article 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28022558/create-greasemonkey-script-to-remove-certain-html-lines-when-found) [Article 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12785185/greasemonkey-look-for-a-string-between-two-elements)

I would like to remove "This Week in Anime" articles from the sidebar on animenewsnetwork.com sites, an example of the code I would like to remove is:

```
<div class="herald box column" data-topics="article141022 column anime">
  <div class="category-line column"></div>
  <div class="thumbnail" data-src="/thumbnails/cover400x200/cms/this-week-in-anime/141022/g24.png.jpg">
    <div class="overlay">
      <div class="category column">column</div>
      <div class="comments"> <a href="/cms/discuss/141022">51 comments</a> </div>
    </div>
    <a href="/this-week-in-anime/2018-12-20/.141022" data-track="id=66149&amp;from=HP.MF"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="wrap">
    <div>
      <h3>
        <a href="/this-week-in-anime/2018-12-20/.141022" data-track="id=66149&amp;from=HP.MF">This Week in Anime - Is Back Street Girls: Gokudols Worth Watching?</a>
      </h3>
      <div class="byline">
        <time datetime="2018-12-20T19:31:04Z" title="2018-Dec-20 11:31:04 -0800 (1.4 day ago)">Dec 20, 14:31</time>
        <div class="comments"> <a href="/cms/discuss/141022">51 comments</a> </div>
        <span class="topics"> <span class="anime">anime</span> </span>
      </div>
      <div class="preview">
        <span class="intro">Netflix's newest anime acquisition is controversial to say the least. Andy and Steve find out (the hard way) if there's any decent comedy hiding under this show's initial shock factor.
        </span>
        <span class="full">Netflix's newest acquisition, Back Street Girls: Gokudols, is controversial to say the least. This week, Andy and Steve find out if there's any decent comedy hiding under this show's initial shock factor. Disclaimer...
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like to remove this entirely, I tried, what I think was searching for the string "this-week-in-anime" and then removing or hiding it's parent , but I never got it to work.

I tried things like these:

```
var badDivs = $("div div:contains('this-week-in-anime')");
badDivs.hide ();
```

and

```
var badDivs = $("div div:contains(this-week-in-anime)");
badDivs.parent ().hide ();
```

and

```
$('li:contains("this-week-in-anime")').parent().hide();
```

---

Edit: Script's final form and advice received elsewhere.

```
 ==UserScript==
// @name     _Anime News Network, remove "This Week in Anime" articles
// @match    *://www.animenewsnetwork.com/*
// @grant    none
// @run-at   document-idle
// ==/UserScript==

(function () {
    'use strict';
    if (!Element.prototype.matches) {
        Element.prototype.matches =
            Element.prototype.matchesSelector ||
            Element.prototype.mozMatchesSelector ||
            Element.prototype.msMatchesSelector ||
            Element.prototype.oMatchesSelector ||
            Element.prototype.webkitMatchesSelector;
    }

    var getParent = function (node, selector) {
        while (node && node.parentNode) {
            node = node.parentNode;
            if (node.matches(selector)) {
                return node;
            }
        }
    };

    document.querySelectorAll(".thumbnail > a[href*='this-week-in-anime']").forEach(function (v) {
        var node = getParent(v, '.herald.box');
        if (node) {
            node.remove();
        }
    });
})();
```

> Some things to consider:
>
> Encapsulate your stuff in a function. This prevents things you declare to be accessible from the page itself.
>
> `"use strict";` as the first line in a function fixes some JS annoyance you might not catch immediately. For example a typo in a
>   variable name.
>
> Try to avoid using `@require`. This can block page loads for a long time if that resource has trouble being delivered
>
> If you want to remove elements, `@run-at document-idle` is a good start because it makes sure the "load" event has fired
>
> If the element you want to remove is dynamically loaded at a later time, use a `setInterval` or better `MutationObserver`
>
> Try to avoid jQuery. Most of it's features are available in regular JS by now.
>
> In my example I completely remove the node. If you don't want that,
>   you can use `node.style.display='none'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, [that first article you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9169032/how-to-use-greasemonkey-to-selectively-remove-content-from-a-website) has the technique you need.  Since your target page adds the offensive content using javascript, you need to use something like `waitForKeyElements()`.

Note that `:contains` searches for text, but the offending "this-week-in-anime" is in various node attributes.  So, we look for links with it in their `href`.

Here's the configuration for [your target website](https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/):

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _Anime News Network, remove "This Week in Anime" articles
// @match    *://www.animenewsnetwork.com/*
// @require  https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant    none
// ==/UserScript==
//-- WARNING: Using the page's copy of jQuery.  This may blow up at some point.
/* global $, waitForKeyElements */

waitForKeyElements (".thumbnail > a[href*='this-week-in-anime']", hideContainerNode);

function hideContainerNode (jNode) {
    //-- jQuery closest() finds an ancestor of current node.
    var containerNode = jNode.closest (".herald.box");
    containerNode.hide ();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it didn't quite work for me as is, but it gave me a much better base that with help on another site lead me to it's final form, I'll update the question with the end result, as well as some tips that I was given about it.